# Not sure how to extract html tag elements with python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the html tags for other uses, but it seems the arrangement of the html file prevents me using ordinary codes I can find to locate the elements

The element is rather long (there are 70+ options in the list), so I am showing only the first few items here:

```
<select title="Please select Automatic Weather Observations" id="aws" onchange="changeYearDropDown2()">
    <option value="">===Manned Weather Station===</option>
    <option value="HKO">Hong Kong Observatory</option>
    <option value="HKA">Hong Kong International Airport</option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="">===Automatic Weather Station===</option>
    <option value="BR1">Beas River</option>
    <option value="BHD">Bluff Head</option>
    <option value="CP1">Central Pier</option>
    <option value="CCH">Cheung Chau</option>
    <option value="CPH">Ching Pak House(Tsing Yi)</option>
```

What I actually want are the values inside the  tag AND the full name of stations as two separate lists. And since there are also some 'blank' tags in the html, I just don't know how to get rid of them and extract only those with values and names...

Any help is appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance!!

Here are some methods I tried, and I don't know why the find_all or find_elements fail:

Using BeautifulSoup:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
  
url = 'https://www.hko.gov.hk/en/cis/climat.htm'
  
req = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')

#method 1
print(soup.select)    #it prints the whole document for me
print(soup.option)    #empty list

#method 2
titles = soup.find_all('option')
print(titles)    #empty list
```

Using Selenium:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

service = Service(executable_path="path/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
#initialize web driver
with webdriver.Chrome(service=service) as driver:
    #navigate to the url
    driver.get(url)

#method 3: find element by CSS selector
    myDiv = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select option")    #with or without '>' returns the same output, and find_elements ALWAYS gets me an error
    print(myDiv.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
    print(myDiv.get_attribute("innerHTML")) #exc <select></select> results

#method 4: find element by tag name
    myDiv2 = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'select')
    print(myDiv2.get_attribute("outerHTML"))    
    #by far the 'best': return a long line of html with all the html tags and name of stations

#method 5: run a loop
    #still in the same with function shown above
    list = []
    for r in range(1,74):    #there are 73 list elements
        value = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[1]/select/option["+str(r)+"]").text
        list.append(value)
    print(list)
    #not bad but I still can't get the tag values
    #using print() just gives me blank list
```

Comment: _"And since there are also some 'blank' tags in the html, I just don't know how to get rid of them and extract only those with values and names..."_ - well, extract all of them and then remove the empty ones, as the simplest solution. BTW, since you probably want those two lists to be related to eachother, don't create two lists - create a dict instead.

Comment: you are right!! Thanks for the suggestion, will go make one!

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the options to load. Most probably the options are being dynamically generated in JS so that's why beautifulsoup is not working.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Ignore the following settings: (for setup purposes only)
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
URL = 'https://www.hko.gov.hk/en/cis/climat.htm'
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(3) # wait for options to be loaded

optionContainer = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="aws"]')
options = optionContainer.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "option")

for option in options:
  name = option.get_attribute("textContent")
  value = option.get_attribute("value")
  if len(name)>0 and len(value)>0:
    print(name, value)
    # do something

driver.quit()
```

Comment: I just wonder why one needs specifying `id='aws'` in the process, because I thought there is only one `<select></select>` tag in the whole page

Comment: I didn't check if there was other <select> tags in the html. If there's only one, then there's no need to use id. But I think it's best to select by id because in the future, there could be another <select> in the html.

Comment: will certainly remember that one!! thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You may try with selenium this way:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

driver = Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.hko.gov.hk/en/cis/climat.htm')
options = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'select#aws > option')))
for option in options:
    print(option.get_attribute('value'), option.text)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!! Very neat scraping results indeed!!